# Problem configuring websphere application server behind ingress

Tags: kubernetes, websphere, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running websphere application server deployment and service (type LoadBalancer). The websphere admin console works fine at URL `https://svcloadbalancerip:9043/ibm/console/logon.jsp`

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                                                                                                    AGE
was-svc      LoadBalancer   x.x.x.x   x.x.x.x   9080:30810/TCP,9443:30095/TCP,9043:31902/TCP,7777:32123/TCP,31199:30225/TCP,8880:31027/TCP,9100:30936/TCP,9403:32371/TCP   2d5h
```

But if i configure that websphere service behind ingress using ingress file like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-check
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ibm/console/logon.jsp
        backend:
          serviceName: was-svc
          servicePort: 9043
      - path: /v1
        backend:
          serviceName: web
          servicePort: 8080
```

The url `https://ingressip//ibm/console/logon.jsp` doesn't works.
I have tried the rewrite annotation too.

Can anyone help to just deploy the ibmcom/websphere-traditional docker image in kubernetes using deployment and service. With the service mapped behind the ingress and the websphere admin console should somehow be opened from ingress

Comment: I think your ingress has no idea to use HTTPS on port 9043. You probably can't have the same resource for HTTP and HTTPS to the backend.  The one that uses 9043 would need something like annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"

or https passthrough on the entire port rather than trying to map individual URLs. Ultimately just passing logon.jsp through won't accomplish much anyway

Comment: Check logs of nginx ingress controller pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a helm chart available from IBM team which has the ingress resource as well. In your code snippet, you are missing SSL related annotations as well.

- https://hub.helm.sh/charts/ibm-charts/ibm-websphere-traditional
- https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-websphere-traditional

I have added the Virtual Host configuration for admin console to work with port 443 in the following code sample.

**Please Note:** Exposing admin console on the ingress is not a good practice. Configuration should be done via `wsadmin` or by extending the base Dockerfile. Any changes done through the console will be lost when the container restarts.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: websphere
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - name: admin
     port: 9043
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 9043
     nodePort: 30510
   - name: app
     port: 9443
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 9443
     nodePort: 30511
  selector:
    run: websphere
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: websphere-admin-vh
  namespace: default
data:
  ingress_vh.props: |+
    #
    # Header
    #
    ResourceType=VirtualHost
    ImplementingResourceType=VirtualHost
    ResourceId=Cell=!{cellName}:VirtualHost=admin_host
    AttributeInfo=aliases(port,hostname)
    #

    #   
    #Properties
    #
    443=*

    EnvironmentVariablesSection
    #
    #
    #Environment Variables
    cellName=DefaultCell01
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: websphere
  name: websphere
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ibmcom/websphere-traditional
    name: websphere
    volumeMounts:
    - name: admin-vh
      mountPath: /etc/websphere/
    ports:
    - name: app
      containerPort: 9443
    - name: admin
      containerPort: 9043
  volumes:
  - name: admin-vh
    configMap:
      name: websphere-admin-vh
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-check
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true" 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /ibm/console
        backend:
          serviceName: websphere
          servicePort: 9043
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I even used the helm chart for the deployment but in that case also the ingress is mapped to the application deployed in websphere. Using ingress i can access the application even now mapping path to 9080 port to WAS service but  want to access the admin console page of websphere which runs on port 9043 from ingress and that is not happening even in the ingress defined in the helm

Comment: ``` $ helm install websphere ibm-charts/ibm-websphere-traditional --version 1.3.0 --set ingress.enabled=true
NAME: websphere
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Aug 21 09:47:50 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
+ Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export INGRESS_IP=$(kubectl get nodes -l proxy=true -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.addresses[?(@.type==\"Hostname\")].address}")
  export APP_PATH=/
  echo https://$INGRESS_IP$APP_PATH ```

Comment: With the SSL annotations on my Ingress, I was able to get to the admin console, however, console threw an error saying I don't have the virtual host configured for the ingress address and that's expected. I stopped there since it's a success condition. I would need to add more configuration to have the virtual host configured. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I am new to websphere..Even i get the problem of virtual host not configured...can you guide how to resolve that error and open the admin page on the ingress domain somehow?

Comment: Hi @Faheem were you able to accees the admin console by adding virtual hosts or something in websphere?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code snippet. Please note that exposing the admin console would be a bad practice since containers are ephemeral and changes should only be make via configuration before the container starts.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing both the adminhost and defaulthost via ingress isn't possible, or at least I've never figured out how to accomplish it. The crux of the issue is that ingress listens on port 80 or port 443 and forwards your request to the corresponding port on the container. Thus, the Host header of your request contains that port. I don't know enough about WAS channels/virtualhosts to understand how this works exactly, but in order for accessing WAS endpoints over any port other than the one listed for the endpoint in WAS config to work, the websphere-traditional image has to set a property to extract the port it should use for things like checking against virtualhost hostalias entries and issuing redirects from the Host header (`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort`).

The problem becomes, when it uses that port, that port needs to be listed as a host alias for the virtual host in order for the traffic to be let through to the application. And since a combination of wildcard host and specific port can only be a host alias on one virtual host at a time, they were set up as host aliases on defaulthost so that web applications will work via ingress, but this makes it impossible to also access the admin console since that is served via a separate virtualhost which doesn't (and as far as I know can't) have the host alias entries set up to allow traffic with port 443 in its host header through. I haven't had to figure out how to get this working because `kubectl port-forward` has been sufficient to get at the admin console for the times I've needed to consult something, and you can't make changes anyway because they'll disappear when the pod restarts and a new one is started from the same (unchanged) image.