# websphere application server behind ingress redirects to dns:port

Tags: kubernetes, websphere, nginx-ingress

I am trying to run websphere behind ingress.
I have successfully configured the ingress for it and I am able to access the console.
The ip on which I am able to access the console is

```
https://mydomain/ibm/console/logon.jsp
```

Note: I have a domain , for which I created a A record.

When I login into the console ,
I am redirected to

```
 https://mydomain:9043/ibm/console/
```

This page does not exist.
If I explicitly run the URL `https://dns/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure`. My application works fine.

Can someone tell me where is the configuration needed so that it is not redirected to dns:port?

I have created all the config following the URL:
[Problem configuring websphere application server behind ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505087/problem-configuring-websphere-application-server-behind-ingress)

Comment: have you tried the two web container custom properties:

trusthostheaderport = true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort = true

Comment: @covener No I have not tried. I am quite new to websphere. Do I need to set these env for my running pod?

Comment: @covener I added these properties. Once I restart my pod all these properties are vanished. Any Idea?

Comment: You need to set them via wsadmin when you build your application container image.

Comment: @ShivangiBhardwaj Please describe your actions taken in a form of an answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Please find the answer

Comment: @covener I did these changes on websphere image 8.5.5.12 and it worked. Now When I am applying the same changes for 8.5.5.17, I get the error "TCPC0003E: TCP Channel TCP_4 initialization failed.  The socket bind failed for host * and port 9443.  The port may already be in use." Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is  `http://hostname/ibm/console/logon.jsp`  and it returns  `http://hostname:9080/ibm/console/logon.jsp`

This is causing confusion and thus we are facing an issue.

The port which our was app uses is controlled by two properties:

```
trusthostheaderport = true 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort = true
```

These can be created in the WAS Admin console under:

Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > [server_name] > Web Container Settings > Web container > Additional Properties > Custom Properties

Setting both of these properties with a value of "true" should force WAS to use the front-end port (from the Host header) instead of the Webcontainer port.

Note: You need to restart the service after the change ( restart in case of docker containers)

Please find the documentation [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html).